# Expressjs route mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to create sort of a programatic route generator.

I have a module `./utils/crud.js` like this

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (Model) {
  router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Using CRUD for model: ' + Model.modelName);
  });
  return router;
};
```

And I use it in my main `app.js` like this

```js
const {Report, Room} = require('./utils/models');
const crud = require('./utils/crud');
const reports = crud(Models.Report);
const rooms = crud(Models.Room);
app.use('/reports', reports);
app.use('/rooms', rooms);
```

Where `Report` and `Room` are Mongoose models (which is not relevant but to explain why I'm trying out this approach).

Whenever y try to reach the second endpoint

```
$ curl my.domain.com/rooms/
```

The server know the mapping correctly and logs:

```
GET /rooms
```

But it runs the wrong module:

```
Using CRUD for model: report
```

Why does it allwais run the FIRST middleware for every route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the same router in both cases, try putting `const router = express.Router();` inside your export function

Comment: Seamless. Can you explain the scope outside and within the export function please?

Comment: @demil133 i can try :), in app.use or router.use, you can provide more then one cb, `app.use('/',middleware1,middleware2,endroute);` as long as the middleware1 is executing `next();`  middleware2 is called and so on... in your code above you execute the the same route.use('/',()=>{}), twise so express.route sees it as route.use('/',report,rooms). if the reports method would call next(); it would first say `using CRUD for m.: reports` and then `using CRUD for m.: rooms` but you don't want to chain thouse subroutes i guessed, so the best way is to give every module it's new defined routes.

Answer (score 1):

This code `const crud = require('./utils/crud');` imports router instance from crud.js into app.js. 
The `crud()` function in app.js uses this instance. 
You can put `const express = require('express');` expression into `module.exports` in crud.js. It should help.